# Class Inheritance Error: Child object has no attribute 'a'

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

Consider the following code snippet

```
class parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0

class child(parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super(parent, self).__init__()
        self.b = 9
    def func(self):
        print(self.a, self.b)

c = child()
print(c.b)
print(c.a)
```

The output that I expected was:

9
0

But the error message states that 'child' object does not have attribute 'a'.

If I instead use the parents init method instead of super, I get my desired output.

```
parent.__init__(self)
```

I have read from other posts, super is the recommended way to implement inheritance. My question is how do I inherit parent class attributes initialized by the init method into child class by using super method?

Comment: please, improve your indentation

Comment: typo: change `super(parent, self).__init__()` to `super(child, self).__init__()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @eyllanesc has mentioned in the comment, it was a typo.

super() should have been called on 'child' object.

```
super(child, self).__init__()
```

Answer (score 2):

In python 3, your call to `super()` in the init method is greatly simplified:

```
class parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0

class child(parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.b = 9
    def func(self):
        print(self.a, self.b)

c = child()
print(c.b)
print(c.a)
print(c.func())
```

#### output:

```
9
0
0 9
```